# typescript I can't import choices.js by "import" command

Tags: typescript

I can't import choices.js by "import" command:

```
import Choices from 'choices.js';

TS2307: Cannot find module 'choices.js'
```

And this doesn't work:

```
import Choices from '../../node_modules/choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.js';

TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../../node_modules/choices.j
s/public/assets/scripts/choices.js'. '/project/node_modules/choices.js/public/assets/scr
ipts/choices.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

And this too:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/choices.js/types/index.d.ts" />
import Choices from '../../node_modules/choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.js';


TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../../node_modules/choices.j
s/public/assets/scripts/choices.js'. '/project/node_modules/choices.js/public/assets/scr
ipts/choices.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Only this command are working:

```
const Choices = require(`choices.js`);
```

But i haven't this problem with loadash and it imported without any problems:

```
yarn add -D lodash @types/lodash

import lodash from 'lodash';
```

I'm do something wrong, but i can understand, where i make mistake and how to solve it. :(

**Update:**
es6 import work for me only if i set noImplicitAny from true to false in tsconfig.json and use absolute path to js file in this library in my .ts file:

```
import * as Choices from '../../node_modules/choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.js';
```

My version there is a problem with types...

Comment: Are you sure you have choices.js installled?

Comment: Yes, of course. const Choices = require(`choices.js`); is working. Problem only with import command. Version of choices.js is last 6.0.2

Comment: `import Choices from 'choices.js';` works perfectly for me (`6.0.2`) with `strict` enabled. Could you share your `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem: it is necessary just
`to set "moduleResolution": "node" in my tsconfig.json`,
then not relative import will begin to work.

Path to types in package.json of this package works only if i write:

```
import Choices from 'choices.js';
```

Not an:

```
import  Choices from 'choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.js';
```

Karol Majewski, thanks for your help. You pushed me to the decision.

Answer (score 0):

After importing your JS file,  just add ...

**import Choices from 'choices.js';**

**declare var Choices: any;**

Comment: It is can't help me. I have got "noImplicitAny": true in my tsconfig.json

Comment: Can you post the exact error which you are getting? The above answer was the actual way to import any js files in typescript.